# Initializing the basic string of uint16_t

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a const basic string in my class:

```
class foo {
   const basic_string<uint16_t> baz;
};
```

How do I initialize it?

The main goals I want to achieve are those:

- no overhead in creation
- readable for the user so for instance convert from "Potato" rather than from some buffer with numbers (if it is doable)
- cross platform code
- wont generate  compiler warning... company policy

I am using c++11.

Comment: Is there a reason your using a `std::basic_sting` instead of a `std::vector`?

Comment: Yes, it is in the big code base, I haven't written it, needs to stay this way, the previous intialisation was done by casting "\0P\0O\0t ... " string into basic string, but generates allignment warning.

Comment: Why `basic_string<uint16_t>`? Do you mean `basic_string<char16_t>` AKA `u16string`? If you want an array of `uint16_t`, a `vector` or `array` would be far more appropriate.

Comment: As above, no influence on how it is stored, sadly....

Comment: (unrelated) Words in English are separated by full stops/periods ("`.`"), not by commas ("`,`").

Comment: If your company has a "no compiler warnings" policy, then it should also have "no code that is worthy of generating compiler warnings" policy. Can't fathom how this design came about! Can't think of an answer to your question, either.

Comment: That is exactly what I said, but they force me to try and fix the warning in some way. By the way, did you mean sentances? Also sometimes they are separated by question marks.

Comment: @cerkiewny Forced warning "fixes" are often casts. That's not usually a good thing.

Comment: @InternetAussie I am aware of that but we are where we are, as much as I agree with all of you that this should be changed, the world isn't perfect. Lets not change the discussion into debate on right or wrong. "It is not possible because..." is also an accepted answer. But saying that I should change company policy is much harder to implement for me.

Comment: You are trying to convert between pointers to distinct types, only way to shut the compiler up is `reinterpret_cast` and this leads to undefined behaviour.  I suggest  changing the declaration and then fix the other __real__ problems.

Comment: Does this encoding happen to coincide with some wide char representation in your locale? If so, some of the standard wide-char/char16_t (widening from char8_t) conversions might do the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I initialize it?

Using any of the `basic_string` constructors. In your example you have used the default constructor. Here is an example of using the initializer list:

```
const basic_string<uint16_t> baz {
   uint16_t(u't'),
   uint16_t(u'e'),
   uint16_t(u's'),
   uint16_t(u't'),
};
```

---

I suspect that it would be much easier for you to use `std::u16string` instead:

```
const std::u16string baz = u"test";
```

The characters can then later be converted to `uint16_t` (from `char16_t`) when you need that:

```
uint16_t c = baz[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine UTF-16 literals (`u` prefix) with user-defined suffixes:

```
std::basic_string<uint16_t> operator "" _u16(char16_t const *begin, std::size_t len)
{
    std::basic_string<uint16_t> str;

    if (begin != nullptr && len != 0) {
        char16_t const *end = begin + len;

        str.reserve(len);

        std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(str));
    }

    return str;
}
```

Now you can initialize your strings like so:

```
std::basic_string<uint16_t> str{u"testing"_u16};
```

There is no more overhead with this approach than there is creating a "standard" `std::string` from a string literal, as in either approach the string must be copied into a new heap allocation.

Comment: If it is const basic_string will overhead not be eliminated during the runtime by compiler doing conversion compile time? The operator ""_u16 could be constexpr right?

Comment: @cerkiewny Theoretically the compiler could optimize creation of a `const std::string` from a string literal by having the string's own pointer point at the string literal -- however, this would require some form of special support from the standard library, to ensure that the `std::string` destructor does not attempt to `delete[]` the allocation. I'm not aware of any compilers that even attempt such an optimization.

Comment: The operator cannot be `constexpr` because *none* of `basic_string`'s members are `constexpr`. Keep in mind that `basic_string` does heap allocations, something that *cannot* be evaluated at compile time.